# Will Allah forgive me for violating poor people's right?

Tags: allah

The incident is about 4 years ago and I was 17.Once I was coming home by rickshaw from coaching centre. I didn't have enough money to pay the rickshaw puller.So I gave him half money and told him to wait as I was gone to bring the money.It took me a bit time since my parents were not at home. When I was gone one of my uncle told the rickshaw puller to go away.So I couldn't give him the full money.Now I am 19 and extremely shameful for that.I know we should never violate the rights of poor people. Somehow I did. Will Allah forgive me?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do it intentionally.It was your uncle who told him to go and you were about to give him money.So,I don't think it's your fault.But I hope if you repent Allah will forgive you.He's most merciful and forgiving.So,don't worry and repent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your fault. If you repent sincerely and promise to never do it again you will forgiven. You should ask forgiveness for him and give charity if possible.